# Regex match text starting with word in a set

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have wish to match something like below in html sources:

```
MoWe 04:30PM - 05:50PM
Fr 12:00PM - 01:20PM
```

The rule is that the text must start with one or more words in the set `{Mo, Tu, We...}` and have a formatted time afterwards. (I do want the whole thing matched weekday + time)

I know `(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)` can grab the weekdays and latter time can be captured with `[\d:- PM]{17}`, how can I glue the regex together?

Thanks for your help in advance!

---

Thanks fellas, the regexes work like magic!

Comment: Do your days of the week follow an order? Like Sa can't appear before Mo. It means like SaSuMo is invalid while MoSaSu is valid

Comment: @Fede Well, good point. Luckily I don't need to check that. :)

Comment: Ok, in the case you need that I also provided you with a regex that helps you with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+\s\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)\s-\s\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)
```

[Debuggex demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/12eyhvyVq7dUaz3H):

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Python demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+\s\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)\s-\s\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)")
>>> pattern.match('MoWe 04:30PM - 05:50PM').group(0)
'MoWe 04:30PM - 05:50PM'
>>> pattern.match('Fr 12:00PM - 01:20PM').group(0)
'Fr 12:00PM - 01:20PM'
```

Comment: I think you need to remove *.

Comment: @alecxe btw, how can I get all matches with `re.findall`, I seem to forget a lot about regex.

Comment: @Ray check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) first. In case you have problems using it, just ask.

Comment: @alecxe for example, `re.findall(r'(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+\s\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)\s-\s\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)', s)` only gives me stuff like `[('Mo', 'PM', 'PM'), ('Fr', 'PM', 'PM')]`, grouped of three parts enclosed with `()`. How can I get the result like `['Mo 04:30PM - 05:50PM', 'Fr 12:00PM - 01:20PM']` directly? Thanks

Comment: @Ray gotcha, you need to change the regexp a bit and use non-capturing groups: `(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+\s\d{2}:\d{2}(?:AM|PM)\s-\s\d{2}:\d{2}(?:AM|PM)`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @alecxe Yep, I guess I need to catch up with the concept of non-capturing groups. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
^(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)\s*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}A?P?M\s*-\s*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}A?P?M
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jI3wB6)

OR

```
(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+\s*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}A?P?M\s*-\s*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}A?P?M
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iF0nG5)

Python code:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+\s*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}A?P?M\s*-\s*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}A?P?M")
>>> str="""MoWe 04:30PM - 05:50PM
... Fr 12:00PM - 01:20PM
... foo"""
>>> m=re.findall(pattern, str)
>>> m
['MoWe 04:30PM - 05:50PM', 'Fr 12:00PM - 01:20PM']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to achieve this:

```
((?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+)\s*[\d: PM-]{17}
```

Visualization:

[image: Debuggex screenshot]

The `(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)` part matches any of the week day. Repeated occurrences of capturing groups aren't captured in normal cases, so in order to capture the entire week day words, we enclose it in another capturing group — which *actually* captures the required week day words.

Then `\s*` matches optional whitespace in between the week day words and the timestamp.

`[\d: PM-]` is a character class that matches any number from 0-9, a colon (`:`), the letters `PM`, or a hyphen (`-`). Note that I've changed the position of the hyphen from the middle to the end — this was done in order to prevent it from being interpreted as a "range" meta-character. The `{17}` quantifier makes sure that the string is matched *only* if there is *exactly* 17 occurrences of the characters in the character class.

Note, however, that this regex will also match a lot of invalid timestamps. I was just pointing out what was wrong with the original regular expression in your question. If you want to account for some sort of validation too, perhaps take a look at [*alecx's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370257/1438393). Better yet, parse the timestamp string out of the raw text, and use Python's built-in functions to handle with date/time. A regex isn't the best tool for that kind of jobs.

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rY9gY3)

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right way. So if your text matches what you showed you can use:

```
(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su).+
```

But if your format can be different you can use a more specific regex like:

```
(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)+\s+\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)\s+-\s+\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)
```

[image]

On the other hand, if your days of the week **must** follow the natural order, like `Fr` shouldn't appear before `Mo`, then you should use:

```
(Mo)?(Tu)?(We)?(Th)?(Fr)?(Sa)?(Su)?\s+\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)\s+-\s+\d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)
```

[image]